# Need a Count, but Multiple other fields

Tags: sql, select, count

I have a table that looks like this:

```
person    trip_id    date    home      destination
joe       1          3/10    chicago   new york
joe       2          4/10    chicago   l.a.
joe       3          5/10    chicago   boston
luther    4          3/12    new york  chicago
luther    5          3/18    new york  boston
```

I want to get a result like

```
person    trips    firstDate   home
joe       3        3/10        chicago
luther    2        3/12        new york
```

Currently I've got
Select
person,
count(trip_id) as trips,
min(date) as firstDate
from [table]
group by person
order by firstDate

I can't figure out how to get home in there as well.

Home is always unique to the person. But my DBMS doesn't know that.

Is there an easy way around this problem?

Appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried to get home in the output, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select person, count(trip_id) as trips, min(date) as firstDate, home
from [table]
group by person, home
order by firstDate
```

Comment: Wow. Wouldn't have thought to do that. Thanks!